# Android - Test mobile app in tablet

Tags: android, mobile

I am creating an android application which is for both android mobile phones and tablet. I am having only android tablet to test the app(We can test using emulators with different screen sizes). Is it possible to test android mobile apps on android tablet but not in full screen? real size in the middle of the screen(Like IOS: In Ipad, we can test the iphone app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Is it possible to test android mobile apps on android tablet but not in full screen?
```

No , this is not possible.

- To test on android phone you need to test on actual device or an emulator only
- In the graphics layout of the xml there is a option to select device size ,the default is Nexus one.Using this option you can preview the layout for different screen sizes .

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check with "graphics layout of the xml - select device size" option.